# Play music on iPhone via a mixer with wireless connection

Tags: iphone, wifi

I want to play musi from my iPhone on a sound system but connected to the mixer wirelessly.

What interface an I get to plug into the mixer that would receive the music output. Looking at distance of about 25 yards and no wi fi hotspot available.

Or can I remotely control An iPad or Mac hard wired to the mixer wirelessly with an iPhone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can control iTunes on a Mac or PC easily from an iPhone, using [Remote](https://www.apple.com/apps/remote/) which I think would be a lot more reliable than trying to establish a solid bluetooth/wifi connection to stream music to an audience who may not appreciate the occasional silence if the connection goes down ;)

Use it with a running playlist & even if you temporarily lose connection from the remote, at least it will never go quiet.

Comment: Thanks - only problem with this solution is I don't have a wi fi network to facilitate this in the venue (sports hall)

Comment: Set up an ad hoc network - http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-set-up-an-ad-hoc-wireless-network.html

Comment: Given the distance involved use this method.  25 yards is 75 feet and that's too far for reliable bluetooth especially when we don't know how much interference will be generated by the audience with every device they are carrying.